# htaccess non-www to www redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In our .htaccess we are currently using this rule to force all non-www links to be www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, we ran into an issue where www.mysite.comwww.mysite.com somehow got logged.  While correcting the error that created the link is important, we want to make sure that THIS instance gets redirected as well.

After searching on google I see many suggestions of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However this does not work at all on our site, as even bob.mysite.com doesn't move to www.mysite.com

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I managed to get it working, using this code:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301, L]`